# NodeJS API saying that the certificate has expired while it's not

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm developing an API with NodeJS, and I've recently updated the certificate. The certificate is valid, but my API shows me an error saying that the certificate is not valid while at the same time it shows the right expiration date.

```
{ daysRemaining: 32,
  valid: false,
  validFrom: '2021-07-12T08:50:22.000Z',
  validTo: '2021-10-10T08:50:21.000Z',
  validFor: [ '*.domain.com' ] }
```

**Environment**:

My API is in an Ubuntu Docker container

NodeJS version: v10.19.0

Certificate: Let's Encrypt

**What I tried:**

I've checked the date of my server and it's valid.

I also tried to clean the server's cache.

I've updated nodeJS.

---

The weird part is that when I call my API sometimes it works and sometimes it says the certificate has expired.

If someone has had the same issue or has an idea how to fix it, I would be so thankful.

Comment: I've started getting this too for a little API I run on super-old CentOS 6 servers (that I'll upgrade at some point, but it's literally just pinging something and then sending me a result). Just started happening today, on Node.js 4.x (heh, I should probably upgrade that too someday! Server's been running for about 10 years).